# Running Multiple Tasks in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm developing a realtime software that I have some non real time functions.

Specs:

- Need do the **method1** in real time;
- Need do the **method2** each 60 minutes.

Should I use multithreading? Tasks?

Now I'm using timers but don't think that it's a good use for it.

Comment: For which platform are you developing? Web, mobile, forms, etc...? Thanks for the hug btw

Comment: For constant monitoring or time-critical events use a thread. Something which needs to be don every 60 minutes can be done by a timer. If it's a long running procces you'll probably want to run it at an own thread (or as a task).

Comment: How "real time" is the real-time method? What are the timing constraints?

Comment: I'm developing a Windows Service for Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: It must be really real time, Ron. If I put a file in the folder now, it should start to be consumed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally a bad idea to have file processing start immediately a file appears in a folder. For example if 100 files arrive at once then you will end up with 100 threads all competing for the same physical resources, e.g. disk heads etc. The best approach, in my opinion, is to have a ***real-time***, or at least as real time as can be achieved with .Net notification that a new file exists and then process these using a producer-consumer queue

Preferably using a thread safe collection such as [ConcurrentQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) with the number of active long running, e.g. emailing threads in process at any time controlled by a synchronization mechanism such as [SemaphoreSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim(v=vs.110).aspx)

Notification of newly created files in a directory can be easily achieved using the [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) class. Execution of processing in a time based manner should, ideally, use the [Observer Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817669.aspx)

I have created a simple application below to demonstrate these concepts which should help.

The application consists of a number of key classes

1. The **SingletonBase** class which implements the [Singleton Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) for classes which should be only instantiated once, e.g. the filesystemwatcher class
2. The **FileSystemMonitor** class which monitors a directory for new files being created and **immediately** notifies the processing queue that a new file exists. 
   Naturally you could very easily modify this to begin immediate processing of a file, but as stated above, this is generally a bad idea
3. The **FilesWorker** class which handles the queue access and related task synchronization.

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Concurrent;
   using System.Globalization;
   using System.Reactive.Linq;
   using System.Reflection;
   using System.Threading;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Security.Permissions;


   namespace ConsoleApplication9
   {
       internal class Program
       {

           private static void Main(string[] args)
           {


               const string directorytowatch = @"d:\junk\watch\"; // the directory to watch for new files
               // this initiates a filesystemmonitor to watch for new files being created 
               Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FileSystemMonitor.Instance.WatchDirectory(directorytowatch));          

               // initiate the processing of any new files
               FilesWorker.Instance.ReadQueue();
               Console.ReadLine();

           }


       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Monitors the filesystem in "real-time" to check for new files
       /// </summary>
       [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
       internal class FileSystemMonitor : SingletonBase<FileSystemMonitor>
       {
           private FileSystemMonitor()
           {
           }

           internal void WatchDirectory(string dir)
           {
               var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(dir)
               {
                   NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.LastAccess,
                   Filter = "*.*"
               };

               // watch all files
               watcher.Created += WatcherOnCreated;
               watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
           }

           private static void WatcherOnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs fileSystemEventArgs)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(fileSystemEventArgs.FullPath + "" + fileSystemEventArgs.ChangeType); // for test purposes
               var fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileSystemEventArgs.FullPath);
               FilesWorker.Instance.AddToQueue(fileInfo);
           }
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// handles the queue of files to be processed and the syncronisation of tasks related to the queue
       /// </summary>
       internal class FilesWorker : SingletonBase<FilesWorker>
       {
           private FilesWorker()
           {
           }

           /// <summary>
           /// The queue of files which still need to be processed
           /// </summary>
           private readonly ConcurrentQueue<FileInfo> _filesQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<FileInfo>();

           /// <summary>
           /// create a semaphore to limit the number of threads which can process a file at any given time
           // In this case only allow 2 to be processed at any given time
           /// </summary>
           private static readonly SemaphoreSlim Semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(2, 2);

           /// <summary>
           /// add new file to the queue
           /// </summary>
           /// <param name="fileInfo"></param>
           internal void AddToQueue(FileInfo fileInfo)
           {
               _filesQueue.Enqueue(fileInfo);
           }

           /// <summary>
           /// executes a method on a given timeframe
           /// </summary>
           /// <param name="method">method to execute</param>
           /// <param name="timer">time between execution runs (seconds)</param>
           internal void ExecuteMethod(Action method, double timer)
           {
               IObservable<long> observable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timer));
               // Token for cancelation
               var source = new CancellationTokenSource();

               observable.Subscribe(x =>
               {
                   var task = new Task(method);
                   task.Start();
               }, source.Token);

           }

           /// <summary>
           /// Get any new files and send for processing
           /// </summary>
           internal void ReadQueue()
           {
               // check the queue every two seconds
               ExecuteMethod(ProcessQueue, 2d);            
           }

           /// <summary>
           /// takes files from the queue and starts processing
           /// </summary>
           internal void ProcessQueue()
           {
               try
               {
                   Semaphore.Wait();
                   FileInfo fileInfo;
                   while (_filesQueue.TryDequeue(out fileInfo))
                   {
                       var fileProcessor = new FileProcessor();
                       fileProcessor.ProcessFile(fileInfo);
                   }
               }
               finally
               {
                   Semaphore.Release();
               }
           }

       }

       internal class FileProcessor
       {
           internal void ProcessFile(FileInfo fileInfo)
           {
               // do some long running tasks with the file
           }
       }


       /// <summary>
       /// Implements singleton pattern on all classes which derive from it
       /// </summary>
       /// <typeparam name="T">Derived class</typeparam>
       public abstract class SingletonBase<T> where T : class
       {

           public static T Instance
           {
               get { return SingletonFactory.Instance; }
           }

           /// <summary>
           /// The singleton class factory to create the singleton instance.
           /// </summary>
           private class SingletonFactory
           {

               static SingletonFactory()
               {
               }

               private SingletonFactory()
               {
               }

               internal static readonly T Instance = GetInstance();

               private static T GetInstance()
               {
                   var theType = typeof(T);
                   T inst;
                   try
                   {
                       inst = (T)theType
                           .InvokeMember(theType.Name,
                               BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Instance
                               | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                               null, null, null,
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                   }
                   catch (MissingMethodException ex)
                   {
                       var exception = new TypeLoadException(string.Format(
                           CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                           "The type '{0}' must have a private constructor to " +
                           "be used in the Singleton pattern.", theType.FullName)
                           , ex);
                       //LogManager.LogException(LogManager.EventIdInternal, exception, "error in instantiating the singleton");
                       throw exception;
                   }

                   return inst;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your help!