# I can't deal with the fileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

Today my problem is in that i can't deal with the fileSystemWatcher (even with debug).
So... i want to use the function GetHashFromFile(string path, HashAlgorithm algorithm ) while the fileSystemWatcher is watching the choosen directory. Once it gets an change in this directory (File has been created, re-named, change..) i want to use the e.fullPath as 1st argument in GetHashFromFile, but it throws me an exception about that this file can't be found. Could someone tell me on wich place in the code should i use the GetHashFromFile() ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample code which I created for a different [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121078/running-multiple-tasks-in-c-sharp/32247349#32247349) which correctly uses FileSystemWatcher to process files which should meet your needs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Concurrent;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Reactive.Linq;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Security.Permissions;


    namespace ConsoleApplication9
    {
        internal class Program
        {

            private static void Main(string[] args)
            {


                const string directorytowatch = @"d:\junk\watch\"; // the directory to watch for new files
                // this initiates a filesystemmonitor to watch for new files being created 
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FileSystemMonitor.Instance.WatchDirectory(directorytowatch));

                // initiate the processing of any new files
                FilesWorker.Instance.ReadQueue();
                Console.ReadLine();

            }


        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Monitors the filesystem in "real-time" to check for new files
        /// </summary>
        [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        internal class FileSystemMonitor : SingletonBase<FileSystemMonitor>
        {
            private FileSystemMonitor()
            {
            }

            internal void WatchDirectory(string dir)
            {
                var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(dir)
                {
                    NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.LastAccess,
                    Filter = "*.*"
                };

                // watch all files
                watcher.Created += WatcherOnCreated;
                watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            }

            private static void WatcherOnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs fileSystemEventArgs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fileSystemEventArgs.FullPath + "" + fileSystemEventArgs.ChangeType); // for test purposes
                var fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileSystemEventArgs.FullPath);
                FilesWorker.Instance.AddToQueue(fileInfo);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// handles the queue of files to be processed and the syncronisation of tasks related to the queue
        /// </summary>
        internal class FilesWorker : SingletonBase<FilesWorker>
        {
            private FilesWorker()
            {
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// The queue of files which still need to be processed
            /// </summary>
            private readonly ConcurrentQueue<FileInfo> _filesQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<FileInfo>();

            /// <summary>
            /// create a semaphore to limit the number of threads which can process a file at any given time
            // In this case only allow 2 to be processed at any given time
            /// </summary>
            private static readonly SemaphoreSlim Semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(2, 2);

            /// <summary>
            /// add new file to the queue
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="fileInfo"></param>
            internal void AddToQueue(FileInfo fileInfo)
            {
                _filesQueue.Enqueue(fileInfo);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// executes a method on a given timeframe
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="method">method to execute</param>
            /// <param name="timer">time between execution runs (seconds)</param>
            internal void ExecuteMethod(Action method, double timer)
            {
                IObservable<long> observable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timer));
                // Token for cancelation
                var source = new CancellationTokenSource();

                observable.Subscribe(x =>
                {
                    var task = new Task(method);
                    task.Start();
                }, source.Token);

            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Get any new files and send for processing
            /// </summary>
            internal void ReadQueue()
            {
                // check the queue every two seconds
                ExecuteMethod(ProcessQueue, 2d);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// takes files from the queue and starts processing
            /// </summary>
            internal void ProcessQueue()
            {
                try
                {
                    Semaphore.Wait();
                    FileInfo fileInfo;
                    while (_filesQueue.TryDequeue(out fileInfo))
                    {
                        var fileProcessor = new FileProcessor();
                        fileProcessor.ProcessFile(fileInfo);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    Semaphore.Release();
                }
            }

        }

        internal class FileProcessor
        {
            internal void ProcessFile(FileInfo fileInfo)
            {
                // do some long running tasks with the file
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Implements singleton pattern on all classes which derive from it
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Derived class</typeparam>
        public abstract class SingletonBase<T> where T : class
        {

            public static T Instance
            {
                get { return SingletonFactory.Instance; }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// The singleton class factory to create the singleton instance.
            /// </summary>
            private class SingletonFactory
            {

                static SingletonFactory()
                {
                }

                private SingletonFactory()
                {
                }

                internal static readonly T Instance = GetInstance();

                private static T GetInstance()
                {
                    var theType = typeof(T);
                    T inst;
                    try
                    {
                        inst = (T)theType
                            .InvokeMember(theType.Name,
                                BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Instance
                                | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                                null, null, null,
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    }
                    catch (MissingMethodException ex)
                    {
                        var exception = new TypeLoadException(string.Format(
                            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                            "The type '{0}' must have a private constructor to " +
                            "be used in the Singleton pattern.", theType.FullName)
                            , ex);
                        //LogManager.LogException(LogManager.EventIdInternal, exception, "error in instantiating the singleton");
                        throw exception;
                    }

                    return inst;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there any possible ways without using Reactive Extensions ?

Comment: Sure - the reactive extensions just drive the Observer for processing, you could always just process the file directly FileSystemMonitor class by replacing the FilesWorker.Instance.AddToQueue call, but this is a bad idea. A better approach would be to use a timer in ReadQueue method to call ProcessQueue

Comment: Thanks about the time you spent to help me! I'll try to make it work on someway. Have a nice day :)

Comment: No problem - check out the link here which is where my answer originated for a more complete description of what the Classes are doing - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121078/running-multiple-tasks-in-c-sharp/32247349#32247349